# Help proving inequality involving (PF) eigenvalues/vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonnegative-matrices

I am studying nonnegative matrices and their use in modelling Markov chains. I am curious about the nature of the sequence of partial sums of a spectral decomposition for an irreducible nonnegative matrix, $A$. The matrix $A$ satisfies the Perron-Frobenius theorem, and thus there exists a dominant eigenvalue $\rho_0$ such that $|\rho| > |\rho_i| \ \forall i>0$. The matrix is diagonalizable and hence can be written as a spectral decomposition,
$$
A_{ji} = \sum_m \rho_m u_i^{(m)} v_j^{(m)}
$$
where I denote $u^{(m)}, v^{(m)}$ as the $m^{\text{th}}$ left and right eigenvectors associated to $\rho_m$. I use the normalization condition $\sum_i v_i = 1$ and $\sum_i u_i v_i = 1$.
The sum $\sum_j \left(A^N\right)_{ji}$ is the state probability distribution after $N$ steps. This leads to sums such as
$$
\sum_j A_{ji} = \sum_j \sum_m \rho_m u_i^{(m)} v_j^{(m)} = \sum_m \rho_m u_i^{(m)}
$$

For certain matrices $A^{(c)}$ and $\{A^{(k)}\}$, I have proven the following inequality
$$
\sum_m \frac{\rho_m^{(c)}}{\rho_0^{(c)}} u_i^{(c)(m)} \geq \sum_m \left( \prod_k \frac{\rho_m^{(k)}}{\rho_0^{(k)}} u_i^{(k)(m)}\right)^{\alpha_k}.
$$
I would like to use this to show that
$$ u_i^{(0)(c)}  \geq \prod_k\left( u_i^{(k)(0)}\right)^{\alpha_k}$$
which I have demonstrated with numerous experiments.

Essentially I would like to "extract" the $m=0$ term from either side of the proven inequality, and I am unsure if this is even possible. The problems are: $u_i^{(m)}$ can be complex for $m\neq 0$ (by Perron-Frobenius theorem), but I know that the entire sum is real (because it is related to a probability). I also know that $|\rho| > |\rho_i| $ as mentioned but I'm not sure how I can use it.

My best idea from what I've tried thus far:
$$
\left( \sum_m \frac{\rho_m}{\rho_0} u_i^{(m)} \right)^{N} = \left(u_i^{(0)} + \sum_{m>1} \frac{\rho_m}{\rho_0} u_i^{(m)} \right)^{N} = u_i^{(0)N}\left(1 + \sum_{m>1} \frac{\rho_m}{\rho_0} \frac{u_i^{(m)}}{u_i^{(0)}} \right)^{N}
$$
So somehow I'd like to show that $\sum_{m>1} \frac{\rho_m}{\rho_0} \frac{u_i^{(m)}}{u_i^{(0)}}$ is "small" perhaps, so that I can apply this expansion above and retain the $m=0$ inequality.

Note: Due to the probability interpretations and positivity of $\rho_0 u_i^{(0)}$, the sum $\sum_{m>1} \frac{\rho_m}{\rho_0} \frac{u_i^{(m)}}{u_i^{(0)}}$ is real!

Any thoughts/ideas are greatly appreciated!